# Get a user's avatar and scale it in discord.net

Tags: c#, discord.net

I was working on a command for my Discord bot that could display a user's avatar and I currently have this code that works fine:

```
var users = Context.Message.MentionedUsers;
var subject = users.First();
var eb = new EmbedBuilder();
eb.WithColor(EmbedColor);
eb.WithImageURL(subject.GetAvatarURL());
await ReplyAsync("", false, eb.Build());
```

How can I scale the image when it sends in the embed? Right now it's kind of small and I want to try and make it larger. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If discord's API doesn't provide any way of getting alternate image sizes, you need to do the scaling yourself.

Comment: GetAvatarUrl has a size argument `GetAvatarUrl(ImageFormat format = Auto, ushort size = 128)`

Comment: thanks. i will try that.